# Computed views as functions without arguments instead of getters

Tags: mobx-state-tree

If I re-write the example in the [Views section of the MST's README file](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#views), but using a normal function *without arguments* instead of a getter, will it still be treated as a computed value with same benefits as using a getter?

```
const UserStore = types
    .model({
        users: types.array(User)
    })
    .views(self => ({
        // vs. 'get amountOfChildren()'...
        getAmountOfChildren() {
            return self.users.filter(user => user.age < 18).length
        },
    }))
```

Sorry I'm sure this is a dumb question - it's just for some reason I've never liked those getters too much, and I'm trying FlowType and it doesn't seem to like them either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't, usually functions accept parameters, and getters does'nt.  that's why getters can be memoized if watched by a reaction, and function without args no :)